# Deploying Django/CPython with Maven

Tags: python, django, maven, continuous-integration

I work in a Java/PHP shop (mainly), and a few Python projects are being pushed in this shop, using Python (CPython 2.7.2) with Django (1.4.3). 
For the [Continuous Integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration), we use Maven (along with other tools).

I am looking for successful examples of integrations of Django projects with Maven. By successful, I mean those that give more powers (for releasing, packaging, build process) than burdens (long process, no immediate results of Python methods, like no compiling compared to Java). I am also looking for any documentation on the subject.

So far, I only find this [serie of blog posts](http://www.shiningpanda.com/blog/2012/04/25/python-java-unified-build-process-14/) on how to integrate Python with Maven, which explains on how to integrate a python package development process on Maven. I am looking for similar example on a more specific example, ie, Django.

NB: I am **very** aware of more adapted build and management tools for Python (Fabric, Paver, etc) but I am bound on the use of the same framework used throughout the shop.